# Disk partition creates two folders

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

In Ubuntu 20.04, I have formatted a partition and on my `/media/${USER}/` folder I see two folders:

```
viktormorales@HP-LINUX:/media/viktormorales$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-x---+ 4 root          root          4096 Nov  8 14:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 Nov  5 11:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 viktormorales viktormorales 4096 Nov  8 15:01 Files
drwx------  5 viktormorales viktormorales 4096 Nov  8 14:55 Files1
```

[image: Folders in file manager]

When I click to mount this partition ...

[image: "Other Locations" in file manager]

... the one that is mounted is `Files1`. I see this:

[image: Filename as shown in file manager's address bar]

So, the "desired" name is `Files`, but apparently now it is `Files1`.

I use Linux for web development, and don't know much about partitions. Can you guide me on what is going on here? You can imagine I want my partition to be labeled as just `Files`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not create the directory yourself; and then have it mount by placing it in the file-system table; ie. `/etc/fstab` rather than using GUI tools to mount  (you can have it in fstab & still use GUI tools to mount (ie. not auto-mounted); but it'll now have a specific location to mount to if directed there in fstab)

Comment: OK. The question is unclear to me. You wrote that you formatted a partition. This action doesn't create any folders. You can label a partition as you like and mount it anywhere you like.

Comment: @Pilot6 , I have a disk with two partitions. One with Ubuntu and another one which used to be a "windows" partition I couldn't access from Ubuntu. So I formatted it using GUI and labeled it as "Files". But then this happens. I see two folders on the "/media/viktormorales/" folder.

Comment: @guiverc Ok. I will look further about this. Thanks!

Comment: It is `files1` because you already had a directory named `files`. Same as it is on Windows.

Comment: @NateT apparently I already had a "Files" folder which I didn't notice before. I formatted it again and called it "Backup" and "problem" solved. Thanks!